# Fix corrupted J's files after recovery

Tags: filesystem-corruption

I reinstalled windows 10 on my laptop, and as a result lost all my files. Then I used EaseUs to recover a react native project from local drive, I managed to recover it successfully but the problem I'm facing is some of the Js files and my app.json won't open, I'm using vscode. It shows unsupported encoding or binary and then when I proceed to open it, it shows se weird chars. I tried changing the encoding from utf-8 to all the encodings vscode provides but it still doesn't return to normal. Is there a way to fix this?

See the screenshots below https://i.stack.imgur.com/77Zxt.jpg

Details:
Corrupt: Latin text → Symbol
File system: NTFS
Recovery Tool: EaseUS Data Recovery

Answer (score 0):

Your file looks like random noise or a piece from a binary file,
rather than text.

Evidently, some files were not recovered successfully.

You could try some other recovery tools.
But you should know that the files might be
unrecoverable if their old area on the disk was overwritten by new files.

See the article
[Best Free Data Recovery and File Un-delete Utility](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112020640/https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-data-recovery-file-undelete-utility.htm)
for recommendations, among which the best I have ever tried is
[MiniTool Power Data Recovery](http://www.powerdatarecovery.com/) (commercial).
Its free version can recover 1 GB of files.